Why does multiplication give 1 even though inputs are not 1?
When I'm doing multiplication inside an always block for my variables K_next_num and K_next_denom, I get 1 as the result even though the expressions for them are nonzero. Multiplication also works in a previous if block for e_pre_var.
What could be the reason for this?
Here is some of my code (here is the full version of the code):
parameter phi_sq, d_var, s_var; //all 16 bit parameters
reg [15:0] e_pre_var;
reg [31:0] K_next_num, K_next_denom;

if (counter1024 == 1) begin
            
            K_next_num = phi_sq*e_pre_var + d_var; 
            K_next_denom = phi_sq*e_pre_var + d_var + s_var;
//            K_next = K_next_num / K_next_denom;
            $display("K_next_num=%d, K_next_denom=%d", K_next_num, K_next_denom);
            M_AXIS_OUT_DIVISOR_tdata = K_next_denom;
            M_AXIS_OUT_DIVIDEND_tdata = K_next_num;
            M_AXIS_OUT_DIVISOR_tvalid = 1'b1; // send the numerator and denominator values to the Divider Generator
            M_AXIS_OUT_DIVIDEND_tvalid = 1'b1;
            $display("Time %0t: %d, %d, e_pre_var=%d, phi_sq=%d, d_var=%d, K_next_num=%d S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal=%d, M_AXIS_OUT_DIVISOR_tdata=%d, M_AXIS_OUT_DIVIDEND_tdata=%d", $time, counter, counter1024, e_pre_var, phi_sq, d_var, K_next_num, S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal, M_AXIS_OUT_DIVISOR_tdata, M_AXIS_OUT_DIVIDEND_tdata);

Here is the result I get:
K_next_num=1, K_next_denom=1
Time 205 ns:       1025,          1, e_pre_var=27611, phi_sq= 1183, d_var=35978, K_next_num=1 S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal=0, M_AXIS_OUT_DIVISOR_tdata=         1, M_AXIS_OUT_DIVIDEND_tdata=         1
K_next_num=1, K_next_denom=1
Time 410 ns:       2049,          1, e_pre_var=    1, phi_sq= 1183, d_var=35978, K_next_num=1 S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal=0, M_AXIS_OUT_DIVISOR_tdata=         1, M_AXIS_OUT_DIVIDEND_tdata=         1
K_next_num=1, K_next_denom=1
Time 615 ns:       3073,          1, e_pre_var=    1, phi_sq= 1183, d_var=35978, K_next_num=1 S_AXIS_IN_tdata_kal=0, M_AXIS_OUT_DIVISOR_tdata=         1, M_AXIS_OUT_DIVIDEND_tdata=         1
...


Post your testbench code so we can run a sim.  What do you expect K_next_num and K_next_denom to be?

I don't see an assignment to e_pre_var. In the assignments to K_next_num/…_denom, the sub-expression phi_sq*e_pre_var + d_var is common to both.

I'm not quite sure, but I would recommend trying in order: 1) set K_next_num equal to a hardcoded value instead of the expression, then 2-4) set K_next_num equal to each of the three variables individually, then 5) set K_next_num equal to phi_sq*e_pre_var. At least one of those steps will give you undesired behavior and you can debug from there. If not, then the problem is with adding d_var to the expression. note: these are all changes to make to line 232, run it, then check your output

@InBedded16 Thank you, when I gave K_next_num a constant value and printed it, it showed that it's 0. It's really strange, I have no idea what's causing this since I literally just gave it a nonzero value.

@toolic Here is a link to the folder of the full project. It's a modification of one of Anton Potocnik's projects so it's quite larger than the part I shared in my question. I expect both variables to be something on the order of 10^7.

@user25028310 -  Hi, Thanks for coming back with an answer to your question. In order to effectively mark the topic as solved, please consider "áccepting" your choice of the best answer i.e. click the "tick mark" next to an answer to make it green - either your answer (which can be áccepted after 2024-05-23 @ 15.15 UTC i.e. 48 hrs after the question was asked) or another answer (which can be accepted any time) if one is written & if you consider it the best one.

Turns out the problem was that I did not actually give space for my register K_next_*

If you have an improved version of the original code, which fixes the issue you identified and which may be useful for future readers to learn from, please consider making an [edit] to this answer to include that. TY

What does give space mean in this context?  How does it relate to the Verilog code?
